# How can I handle errors which are not in my code but scripts I use

Tags: python

Some files in capa give an error like :

```
└─$ /bin/python /home/kali/enviorment/data/scan.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1345, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 1254, in main
  File "main.py", line 580, in get_extractor
  File "main.py", line 497, in get_workspace
  File "viv_utils/__init__.py", line 117, in getWorkspace
  File "vivisect/__init__.py", line 2824, in loadFromFile
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 38, in parseFile
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 87, in loadPeIntoWorkspace
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 578, in getMemBaseAndSize
  File "PE/__init__.py", line 1446, in __getattr__
  File "PE/__init__.py", line 732, in parseSections
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
[21437] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

however I have added a try block before running the os cmd however I realized that this issue occours due to the capa script not my code which i reference in my code:

```
─(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ ./capa -v /home/kali/enviorment/data/malware/Backdoor.Win32.DsBot.hgn_2f55.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1345, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 1254, in main
  File "main.py", line 580, in get_extractor
  File "main.py", line 497, in get_workspace
  File "viv_utils/__init__.py", line 117, in getWorkspace
  File "vivisect/__init__.py", line 2824, in loadFromFile
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 38, in parseFile
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 87, in loadPeIntoWorkspace
  File "vivisect/parsers/pe.py", line 578, in getMemBaseAndSize
  File "PE/__init__.py", line 1446, in __getattr__
  File "PE/__init__.py", line 732, in parseSections
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
[26185] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!


path_to_file = '/home/kali/enviorment/data/malware/Backdoor.Win32.Bifrose.dxcg_c70e.exe'
try:
    os.system(f'./capa -v {path_to_file}  > output.txt')

except Exception:
    print(f"{path_to_file} threw an error")
    with open("error.log", "w") as error:
        error.write(f"{path_to_file} threw an error")
```

How can I handle errors which are not in my code but scripts I use

Comment: Use [subprocess instead of os.system](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-os-system)